# On Windows Phone 8, how can I detect if an app is installed with javascript?

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-8

I am opening an application via URL on a Windows Phone. Specifically the Pic2Shop app with the following javascript:

```
<script>
    $('.scanButton').click(function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            // if pic2shop not installed yet, go to App Store
            window.location = "http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/pic2shop/a279c60c-3f09-e011-9264-00237de2db9e";
        }, 25);
        // launch pic2shop and tell it to open Google Products with scan result
        window.location = "pic2shop://scan?callback=http%3A//www.google.com/";
    });
</script>
```

What I would like to do is automatically detect if Pic2Shop is installed and, if not, automatically redirect the user to the appropriate page. The code above assumes that if Pic2Shop is present it will 'instantly' open. If not the timeout will occur and send the user to the appropriate page to install. This in of itself, works great.

My only complaint, is the Windows Phone OS is automatically giving me a message entitled "Search for app in the Store?" which then performs a search. The correct app is listed, but I would rather turn this off and explicitly guide the user. Currently this pop up blinks across the screen before my timeout trumps it.

Is there a way to either:

1. Disable the OS app search
2. Detect whether the app is installed with javascript preemptively so I can write my own logic